# List of setup objects in Salesforce

Tags: setup-object

Does salesforce have any documentation saying which objects are setup objects? I found this

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_setup.htm

But this document doesn't mention other objects like Group, Userrole etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go with the list of setup objects -

The following sObjects can’t be used with other sObjects when performing DML operations in the same transaction:

**FieldPermissions**

**Group**
You can only insert and update a group in a transaction with other sObjects. Other DML operations are not allowed.

**GroupMember**
You can only insert and update a group member in a transaction with other sObjects in Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 14.0 and earlier.

**ObjectPermissions

PermissionSet

PermissionSetAssignment

QueueSObject

ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRule

ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRuleItem

RuleTerritory2Association

SetupEntityAccess

Territory2

Territory2Model

UserTerritory2Association

User**
More information here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm?search_text=mixed