# How to avoid MIXED dml Exception in update operation?

Tags: apex, dml, dmlexception, mixed-dml

I got System.DmlException in update operation. Can anyone please check the below code and help me to resolve the exception.
I have tried to solve it for the last two days but I couldn't find a solution.

### Exception Details :

> common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Update failed.
> First exception on row 0 with id a0q3k00000HXZEgAAP;
> first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object
> (or vice versa): ZTS_EU_Territory__c, original object: Territory2: []"|0x3bb61ff5

### Apex Class:

```
webservice static List < ZTS_EU_Territory__c > updateCustomTerrAssignedFlag() {
    Map < String, Territory2 > terrMap = new Map < String, Territory2 > ();

    //get all territories created today
    List < Territory2 > terrList = getStdTerritoryRecordList();
    //[SELECT Id, name, ZTS_Terr_SFID__c, SystemModstamp FROM Territory2 WHERE SystemModstamp = TODAY AND ZTS_Terr_SFID__c != ''];
    

    for (Territory2 terr: terrList) {
        terrMap.put(terr.ZTS_Terr_SFID__c, terr);
    }
    //get custom territories 
    List < ZTS_EU_Territory__c > cterrList = getTerritoryRecordList(new List<String>(terrMap.keySet()));
    /*[SELECT Id, ZTS_EU_Parent_Territory__c, ZTS_EU_Territory_synced__c, ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c FROM ZTS_EU_Territory__c
        WHERE Id IN: terrMap.keySet() AND ZTS_EU_Market__c != 'United States'];*/

    List < ZTS_EU_Territory__c > cterrToUpdate = new List < ZTS_EU_Territory__c > ();
    for (ZTS_EU_Territory__c cterr: cterrList) {
        if (terrMap.containsKey(cterr.id) && (!cterr.ZTS_EU_Territory_synced__c || String.isBlank(cterr.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c)))
        {
            cterr.ZTS_EU_Territory_synced__c = true;
            cterr.ZTS_EU_Terr_SFID__c = terrMap.get(cterr.id).id;
            cterrToUpdate.add(cterr);
        }
    }
    update cterrToUpdate;

    return cterrToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a suggestion of what to check than an answer but is a bit long for a comment.

Referring to [List of setup objects in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82517/list-of-setup-objects-in-salesforce), `Territory2` is a setup object so the error message would suggest that you are updating `Territory2` before you update `ZTS_EU_Territory__c`.

I assume `getStdTerritoryRecordList` does not update `Territory2`? Also check that there are no triggers or other logic that updates `Territory2` when `ZTS_EU_Territory__c` is updated. (Not sure if updating both in the same transaction is a problem or not so this may not be relevant.)

Can you confirm that the `updateCustomTerrAssignedFlag` method is not being called directly by other Apex code? If it was you would need to review that calling code too.

Also [turn server-side logging on](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) to gather more evidence of what is going on.